# Python How do I put a space in between my variable in an update function problem

Tags: python

Is there any way to put spaces in between my variable in an update function?

```py
d = {Milk: 1, Bake beans: 3}

d.update(Bake beans = 5)
```

[Heres a picture if it explains my question better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zflm.png)

Comment: What is ‘Milk’? You don’t show where this is defined.

Comment: Variable names can't have spaces in them.  That's why your IDE is showing you red squiggly lines; this is simply not valid syntax and you can't do it.  The typical convention for multi-word variable names is to use underscores, e.g. `bake_beans` (aka "snake case" -- all words lowercase, underscores as seperators).

Comment: The keys have to be strings: `{'Milk': 1, 'Baked beans': 3}`. If you want to update just one element, just re-assign it: `d['Baked beans'] = 5`. `update` is really only useful if you want to add multiple new elements to the dict.

Comment: `d = {Milk: 1, Bake beans: 3}` should be showing an error also.

Answer (score 1):

Variable names cannot have spaces. Your first line

```
d = {Milk: 1, Bake beans: 3}
```

fails because (1) there isn't a variable `Milk` and (2) `Bake beans` is not a valid variable name. You likely want the keys to be strings.

```
d = {"Milk": 1, "Bake beans": 3}
```

`dict.update` is used to update a dictionary from another dictionary or something that iterates 2-tuples.

```
>>> help(dict.update)
update(...)
    D.update([E, ]**F) -> None.  Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
    If E is present and has a .keys() method, then does:  for k in E: D[k] = E[k]
    If E is present and lacks a .keys() method, then does:  for k, v in E: D[k] = v
    In either case, this is followed by: for k in F:  D[k] = F[k]
(END)
```

Its not the right method for the thing you want to do. To create/update a single key with a single value, use item assignment

```
d["Bake beans"] = 3
```

Comment: Really nice in-depth answer

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, keyword arguments must be named by an identifier; `"Bake beans"` is not an identifier. You can, however, define a mapping and unpack it using the `**` syntax to provide a set of "implicit" keyword arguments to be passed to a function.

```
d = {"Milk": 1, "Bake beans": 3}

d.update(**{"Bake beans": 5})  # or just d["Bake beans"] = 5
```